# Porterduff Modes(Multiply)

Tags: java, android, bitmap

I wanted to use porterduff multiplication mode to the PNG image, but the background became Black, only the background in the PNG extension picture becomes Black, how can I fix this?

The background should be transparent when I use the multiplication mode I want.

This line of code did not work:

```
view.setLayerType(View.LAYER_TYPE_SOFTWARE, null);
```

I myself wrote code as below but it didn't work and didn't show any pictures.

```
private Bitmap MultiplyBitmap(Bitmap bitmapmultiply){
        Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(bitmapmultiply.getWidth(), bitmapmultiply.getHeight(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
        Canvas cnvs = new Canvas(bitmap);
        Paint pnt = new Paint();
        pnt.setXfermode(new PorterDuffXfermode(PorterDuff.Mode.MULTIPLY));
        cnvs.drawBitmap(bitmapmultiply, 0, 0, pnt);

        Bitmap multiplybitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(bitmapmultiply.getWidth(), bitmapmultiply.getHeight(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
        Canvas canvas = new Canvas(multiplybitmap);
        Paint paint = new Paint();
        paint.setXfermode(new PorterDuffXfermode(PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_IN));
        canvas.drawBitmap(bitmapmultiply,0,0, null);
        canvas.drawBitmap(bitmap, 0, 0, paint);
        return multiplybitmap;
    }
```

How can I remove the black background using Java? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Please, refer to the that [PoterDuff.Mode](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/PorterDuff.Mode) link from Android webstie where you can find a lot of examples.

You could try something like this (just adapt the code for your needs):

Kotlin

```
val bmpDrawable = bmp.toDrawable(res)
bmpDrawable = DrawableCompat.setTint(bmpDrawable, Color.BLACK)
val tintedBmp = bmpDrawable.bitmap

return jokeDao.insert(entity.toDbJoke())
```

Java

```
Drawable bmpDrawable = bmp.toDrawable(res)
DrawableCompat.setTint(bmpDrawable, Color.BLACK)
Bitmap tintedBmp = bmpDrawable.bitmap
```

Comment: I looked but no answer? Can you help more?

Comment: Thanks for the answer, what language is this kotlin? Do you know how I can convert to Java?

Comment: You're perfectly, i'm not at the computer right now, I'll try the code later, thank you very much.